# The HashSet<T>.removeAll method is surprisingly slow

Tags: java, performance, collections, hashset

Jon Skeet recently raised an interesting programming topic on his blog: ["There's a hole in my abstraction, dear Liza, dear Liza"](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/29/there-s-a-hole-in-my-abstraction-dear-liza-dear-liza/) (emphasis added):

> I have a set – a `HashSet`, in fact. I want to remove some items from it… and many of the items may well not exist. In fact, in our test case, *none* of the items in the "removals" collection will be in the original set. This sounds – and indeed *is* – extremely easy to code. After all, we’ve got [`Set<T>.removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) to help us, right?
>
> We specify the size of the "source" set and the size of the "removals" collection on the command line, and build both of them. The source set contains only non-negative integers; the removals set contains only negative integers. We measure how long it takes to remove all the elements using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which isn’t the world most accurate stopwatch but is more than adequate in this case, as you’ll see. Here’s the code:
>
> ```
> import java.util.*;
> public class Test 
> { 
>     public static void main(String[] args) 
>     { 
>        int sourceSize = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
>        int removalsSize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
>         
>        Set<Integer> source = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
>        Collection<Integer> removals = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
>         
>        for (int i = 0; i < sourceSize; i++) 
>        { 
>            source.add(i); 
>        } 
>        for (int i = 1; i <= removalsSize; i++) 
>        { 
>            removals.add(-i); 
>        } 
>         
>        long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
>        source.removeAll(removals); 
>        long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
>        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start) + "ms"); 
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Let’s start off by giving it an easy job: **a source set of 100 items, and 100 to remove:**
>
> ```
> c:UsersJonTest>java Test 100 100
> Time taken: 1ms
> ```
>
> Okay, so we hadn’t expected it to be slow… clearly we can ramp things up a bit. How about a source of one million items and 300,000 items to remove?
>
> ```
> c:UsersJonTest>java Test 1000000 300000
> Time taken: 38ms
> ```
>
> Hmm. That still seems pretty speedy. Now I feel I’ve been a little bit cruel, asking it to do all that removing. Let’s make it a bit easier – 300,000 source items and 300,000 removals:
>
> ```
> c:UsersJonTest>java Test 300000 300000
> Time taken: 178131ms
> ```
>
> Excuse me? Nearly three *minutes*? Yikes! Surely it ought to be easier to remove items from a *smaller* collection than the one we managed in 38ms?

Can someone explain why this is happening? Why is the `HashSet<T>.removeAll` method so slow?

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fast. For you case, it took ~12ms to finished. I've also increase both input values by 10 and it took 36ms. Maybe your PC does some intensive CPU tasks while you run the tests?

Comment: I tested it, and had the same result as the OP (well, I stopped it before the end). Strange indeed. Windows, JDK 1.7.0_55

Comment: There is an open ticket on this: [JDK-6982173](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6982173)

Comment: As [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384564/1709587), this question was originally plagiarised from Jon Skeet's blog (now directly quoted from and linked to in the question, due to a moderator's edit). Future readers should note that the blog post it was plagiarised from does in fact explain the cause of the behaviour, similarly to the accepted answer here. As such, instead of reading the answers here, you may instead wish to simply click through and read [the full blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/29/there-s-a-hole-in-my-abstraction-dear-liza-dear-liza/).

Comment: The bug will be fixed in Java 15: [JDK-6394757](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6394757)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: No, the problem is still not fixed in Java 18. Look at the resolution for the bug ticket, it is set to "Unresolved". The reason is probably that possible solutions have subtle iterations for performance and semantics between `HashSet` and `TreeSet`. See [this discussion](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2020-May/066196.html) on the JDK mailing list for more information.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The behaviour is (somewhat) documented in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

> This implementation determines which is the smaller of this set and the specified collection, by invoking the size method on each. ***If this set has fewer elements***, then the implementation iterates over this set, checking each element returned by the iterator in turn to see ***if it is contained in the specified collection***. If it is so contained, it is removed from this set with the iterator's remove method. If the specified collection has fewer elements, then the implementation iterates over the specified collection, removing from this set each element returned by the iterator, using this set's remove method.

What this means in practice, when you call `source.removeAll(removals);`:

- if the `removals` collection is of a smaller size than `source`, the `remove` method of `HashSet` is called, which is fast.
- if the `removals` collection is of equal or larger size than the `source`, then `removals.contains` is called, which is slow for an ArrayList.

Quick fix:

```
Collection<Integer> removals = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Note that there is [an open bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6982173) that is very similar to what you describe. The bottom line seems to be that it is probably a poor choice but can't be changed because it is documented in the javadoc.

---

For reference, this is the code of `removeAll` (in Java 8 - haven't checked other versions):

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    boolean modified = false;

    if (size() > c.size()) {
        for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            modified |= remove(i.next());
    } else {
        for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: Wow. I learnt something today. This looks like a bad implementation choice to me. They should not do that if the other collection is not a Set.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes that's weird - it been discussed [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2011-July/007148.html) with your suggestion - not sure why it did not go through...

Comment: Thanks a lot @assylias ..But really wondering how did you figure it out..:)
Nice really nice....Did u faced this problem???

Comment: @show_stopper I just ran a profiler and saw that `ArrayList#contains` was the culprit. A look at the code of `AbstractSet#removeAll` gave the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Idea has a built-in code inspection for this usage and a quick fix (provided that you can use java 1.8):

[image: 'set.removeAll(list)' may work slowly]